# Fontasic images not showing in the webpage

Tags: html, css, image, fontastic

a beginner here. I am trying to use Fontastic for a website. Here is how I am using it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/3BksDdMDDYiXnZWaHMVHCd/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <i class="icon-code">a</i> My Title
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

How ever the result I get appears like this:

aMy Title

While it is supposed to show a tiny image. I appreciate any comment, suggestion and code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the contents of your css file. The only icons referenced are `.icon-alignment-aligned-to` and `icon-briefcase`. `icon-code` does not exist.

`icons.css`

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* untitled-font-1 */
@font-face {
  font-family: "untitled-font-1";
  src:url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/3BksDdMDDYiXnZWaHMVHCd/fonts/1417862732.eot");
  src:url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/3BksDdMDDYiXnZWaHMVHCd/fonts/1417862732.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/3BksDdMDDYiXnZWaHMVHCd/fonts/1417862732.woff") format("woff"),
    url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/3BksDdMDDYiXnZWaHMVHCd/fonts/1417862732.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/3BksDdMDDYiXnZWaHMVHCd/fonts/1417862732.svg#1417862732") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: "untitled-font-1" !important;
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: "untitled-font-1" !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-alignment-aligned-to:before {
  content: "a";
}
.icon-briefcase:before {
  content: "b";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/3BksDdMDDYiXnZWaHMVHCd/icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h1>
        <i class="icon-briefcase"></i> My Title
    </h1>
<h1>
        <i class="icon-alignment-aligned-to"></i> My Title
    </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, can I ask how can I add my classes (for specific images) to the css file? Because the css is generated by Fontastic website. Thank you.

Comment: It should generate the CSS for you dependant on what glyphs you select for your font. Most likely the `code` icon is missing from your font file. Try to recreate the font on Fontastic

Comment: It is solved now, I regenerated the css file and the classes were included. Thank you very much :)